# meaning: crashed out in practice

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

A dictionary gives the following example sentence. What does "crash out" mean? Does it refer to defeat in a sports event? But how can there be victory or defeat if the activity is only practicing?

> Schumacher crashed out **in practice** for the Australian grand prix.

Comment: "in practice" approximately equals "actually; in reality"."in practice: an idiom used to say what is actually done or what the actual effect or result of something is  -- by Merriam-Webster".

Comment: @ xbh  But the dictionary's sentence is not given for the "in practice" in the sense of "in reality." https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/practice

Comment: It is a reference to the practice stage of a Formula 1 grand prix. *Crashed OUT* because as a result of the crash he was no longer able to take part.

Comment: According to "collins", "crashed out" means got eliminated from some competition. Though it is informal. Like [this](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crash-out).

Comment: Since they mention the Australian Grand Prix, a car race, discussion of "competitions" or "sporting events" should focus specifically on car racing, where a "crash" surely must refer to a literal *crash* (of the car). Listen to Minty; he (or she?) sounds knowledgeable

Comment: @LorelC. You mean a car accident? If so, why is "out" used?

Comment: @Apollyon In this case, it seems as if *crashed* ***out*** is combining both literal and figurative meanings. Not only did they *crash* but they were also *eliminated*. (And it would be quite awkward to say *crashed and crashed out*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Can someone be said to "be eliminated from a race" if he or she doesn't even participate in it? The example in the OP describes a situation in which a person lost the opportunity to participate in a race because he was (probably) injured.

Comment: If we say someone was "eliminated from a race," does it entail he or she participated in it and lost?

Comment: Yes. In some sports, different specific terminology can be used. For instance, in tennis, if somebody doesn't show up for a match it's called a *walkover*. However, it's still fine to say, prior to a competition, that you need to *retire* from it. (You could also say *withdraw* or *pull out*.) And, of that, other people could say that you were *eliminated (before it even started).*

Comment: A British dictionary defines "crash out" in the figurative sense as "to lose a game with the result that you have to stop playing in a competition." Clearly, that definition is incompatible with the way "crash out" is used in the OP, which refers to the practice stage only.

Comment: And an American told me he would not have used "out" in the OP.